# Implementing `exclusions' in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

How can I modify ListPlot so that I can plot joined data, but exclude joining up adjacent data points that differ by a certain threshold.

E.g. I want to modify the code

```
ListPlot[Table[Tan[x], {x, -Pi, Pi, 0.01}], Joined -> True]
```

so that I don't see the vertical lines at the discontinuities (figure below). I understand this is often taken care of automatically in Plot and can be adapted to one's needs, but I'm not sure how to implement this with ListPlot.

[image]

**Edit**

The answer provided by @corey979 works for this simple example, but isn't suitable for my particular application (I don't want to get bogged down in the details unless necessary). I have an idea that will work for a general discontinuity but not sure how to implement it. Say instead I have the plot given by

```
f[x_] := If[x < 0, 0, 1]
t1 = Table[f[x], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}];
ListPlot[t1, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

how can I get rid of this discontinuity by telling ListPlot to not join the two points either side of 0?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [shown in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440678/how-to-avoid-asymptotes-when-i-listplot-a-table-of-data-using-mathematica), with

```
t = Table[Tan[x], {x, -Pi, Pi, 0.01}];
plot = ListPlot[t, Joined -> True]
```

can do either

```
DeleteCases[plot, Line[_?(Length[#] < 4 &)], Infinity]
```

[image]

or

```
ListPlot[t /. x_ /; Abs@x > 6 -> None, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Regarding the edit in the OP:

```
f[x_] := If[x < 0, 0, 1]
t1 = Table[f[x], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}];
plot = ListPlot[t1, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
plot /. Line[a_] :> Line /@ Split[a, Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 0.1 &]
```

[image]

As [Chip Hurst proposed in a comment (thanks!)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131202/implementing-exclusions-in-listplot/131203?noredirect=1#comment354176_131203), instead of the number `0.1` an automatically selected `threshold` might be used:

```
threshold = 
 Quantile[Join @@ 
   Cases[plot, Line[a_] :> Abs[Differences[a[[All, 2]]]], Infinity], 
  0.999]
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately they don't seem to work for my application. I will update my question.

Comment: You could always histogram all the height differences to determine a threshold. That would help generalize this code to work for an arbitrary plot.

Comment: @ChipHurst How? `Cases[plot, Line[a_] -> a, Infinity][[1, All, 2]] // Differences // 
 Histogram[#, PlotRange -> All] &` on the `plot` of `Tan[x]` doesn't look enlightening.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `threshold = Quantile[Join @@ Cases[plot, Line[a_] :> Abs[Differences[a[[All, 2]]]], Infinity], 0.999]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Indeed. Allow me to incorporate it into the answer :)

Comment: Perhaps 'histogram' wasn't the best word choice in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually split the data then plot. ( For this to work the list needs to be in the `{x,f[x]}` form. )

```
f[x_] := If[x < 0, 0, 1]
ListPlot[Split[
  Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.01}],
  Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < .5 &],
  Joined -> True,PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

of course if the data is already just a list of `f[x]` you can do like this:

```
data = Table[Tan[x], {x, -Pi, Pi, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Split[Transpose[{Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, Length@data - 1], data}],
  ( Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < .1 || #1[[2]] #2[[2]] >= 0) &], 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

for this one I added a condition to only split if there is a sign change *and* a large derivative