# Implementing exclusions in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

How can I stop `ListPlot3D` from drawing segments between data points that differ by a certain threshold? In my example these far separated data points correspond to data samples either side of a discontinuity.

This question is a natural extension of the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131202/implementing-exclusions-in-listplot) for `ListPlot`, and may well be a trivial extension for those who know what they're doing. Or perhaps not.

Here is an example:

```
r = x^2 + y^2;
data = Table[r Tan[r], {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.01}];
ListPlot3D[data, ClippingStyle -> None]
```

I appreciate that here we can split the plotting into two different regions before and after the discontinuity in `Tan`, but in the general case this is not so easy.

[image]

Comment: I tag @corey979, the accepted answerer from the previous question, but with no implied obligation!

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you could pick a plot range (perhaps from a test plot) and use `RegionFunction` to enforce it:

```
ListPlot3D[data, ClippingStyle -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -11 < z < 12]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think this sort of tweaking of plots is for polishing presentations and papers, so using a test plot seems quite practical. However, a semi-automatic way to pick a range might be something like `Quantile[Flatten@data, {0.05, 0.95}]`.